# How to get the absolute paths of foreign libraries from cffi:list-foreign-libraries?

Tags: common-lisp, cffi

Suppose I want to create a dump of the current dynamic libraries used in a Common Lisp application. How I can get the absolute path of foreign libraries given the result of [cffi:list-foreign-libraries](https://github.com/cffi/cffi/blob/78143fd68d4f544587ad20ae97eaa38e327d0ceb/src/libraries.lisp#L192)?

It should be nice if the given solution can be portable operating-system-wise or at least CL implementation-wise.

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation, it appears that once a library is loaded, the `pathname` slot of the `foreign-library` instance representing the library is modified to point to path of resolved object file, *but it is absolute only when the file is not in a standard system location*. For example:

```
(cffi:list-foreign-libraries :loaded-only t)
=> (#<CFFI:FOREIGN-LIBRARY LIBSDL2 "libSDL2-2.0.so.0"> ...)
```

Now it is just a matter of accessing the pathname slot:

```
(mapcar #'cffi:foreign-library-pathname *)
=> (#P"libSDL2-2.0.so.0" ...)
```

But here, you can see that the pathname is not absolute. That's because when CFFI internally called `cffi::%load-foreign-library` (after a bit of tracing) with the following arguments:

```
(cffi::%load-foreign-library "libSDL2-2.0.so.0" "libSDL2-2.0.so.0")
```

... and the implementation found the object file using the system's implicit lookup mechanism (e.g. `dlopen`).

`cffi::%load-foreign-library` is implemented differently on different platforms, and in the case of SBCL, for example, the pointer obtained by `dlopen` is stored in objects inside `SB-SYS:*SHARED-OBJECTS*`, but as far as I know there is no portable way to retrieve the path of the library being loaded from that.

Comment: Thanks, this is a similar conclusion I made. Just to give a some context, I solved in a non-portable way by doing: https://github.com/commonlispbr/starwar/pull/1